# Google Drive Integration with Salesforce Using Service Account

Tags: google-drive-api, salesforce, apex

I was able to create a Google Drive Integration into Salesforce using oAuth. But my problem is, the app redirects the user to login to Google. I want it to log in programmatically so every user is logged in as the same Google Drive user automatically with no extra step. I feel like the only way to do this is with a Service Account in Google Drive. Except looking at the documentation I don't see how to set this up in Apex. Here is the documentation which shows Java:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

Here is my auth uri that works for oAuth (but requires you to login to Google:

```
global class cAuthURIForApiReq {
global String authenticationURI = '';

public cAuthURIForApiReq(String clientKey, String redirect_uri) {
    String key = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(clientKey, 'UTF-8');
    String uri = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(redirect_uri, 'UTF-8');

    String authuri = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?' +
         'client_id=' + key +
         '&response_type=code' +
         '&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' +
         '&redirect_uri=' + uri +
         '&state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://oauth2-login-demo.example.com/myHome' +
         '&login_hint=jsmith@example.com' +
         '&access_type=offline';

    authenticationURI = authuri;
}
```

}

And then to authorize just call this method:

```
 public PageReference driveAuth() {
    PageReference pg = new PageReference(new cAuthURIForApiReq(key, redirect_uri).authenticationURI);
    return pg;
}
```

Anyone know how to authenticate programmatically without being redirected to google to login?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an Named Credential, there is a field called Identity Type. 
 You want to choose Named Principal.  Then you authenticate the app using your Google username/password (or an account you setup for the integration).  All other users then interact with the named credential as you.

Alternatively, you can not use a Named Credential with an Auth Provider and instead write code to use a Service Account credential with a JWT.